# XCUITest - Failed to find matching element

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

In one of my view controllers, I have code like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var _tableView: UITableView!

    private lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
        let searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.isAccessibilityElement = true
        searchBar.accessibilityLabel = "SearchField"
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .none
        searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        searchBar.delegate = self

        return searchBar
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        isAccessibilityElement = true
        accessibilityLabel = "ViewController"

        _tableView.isAccessibilityElement = true
        _tableView.accessibilityLabel = "ItemList"
        _tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    }
}
```

Now whenever I try to record UI test and select the **searchBar**, I get the following error:

> Timestamped Event Matching Error: Failed to find matching element

I tried debugging to get the **searchBar** and following code, but it didn't match any element and assertion fails.

```
    let searchField = app.tables["ItemList"].otherElements.element(boundBy: 0).otherElements["SearchField"]
    XCTAssertTrue(searchField.exists)
```

Can you please show me what I did wrong? How can I access and test the **searchBar**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you provide accessibility properties to UIViewController? It may decrease the accessibility of your app.

Comment: Because I need to test which view controller is presented at certain state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Debug View Hierarchy or the XCode open developer tool Accesibility Inspector from bottom to top looking for the view that isn't accessibility enabled.

Comment: That view was added from code, so **Debug View Hierarchy** is not an option is this case. But the good news is, I found the **SearchField** using Accesibility Inspector. And it is in tableView `otherElements`, not in `element(boundBy: 0).otherElementes`. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know that code generated views doesn't appears, tricky one.

Comment: My bad. Views from code does appear at debugging view hierarchy. I was just impatient to find out from the mess of layers. + 1 for the comment, for which I searched again.

Comment: No prob, at least you tried Accessibility Inspector that worth the try

Answer (score 1):

1. The built-in recorder is bad, you should write test code yourself.
2. Find the element in VoiceOver hierarchy with `print(app.debugDescription)`
3. Your XCUIElementQuery is a little bit longer than it should be. Try to shorten it like `app.otherElements["SearchField"]`